# How do I convert row values into an array?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

How do i insert values into an array from a selection of values from multiple rows in a table in Postgresql.  For example, I have a table with rows of Companies and I would like to combine multiple companies into a single array value of another table?

I tried:

```
Insert into id_companies
select individual, company_name
from company_info.
```

`Company_name` is type `charvar(100)` in table `company_info` and it is type `charvar(100)[]` in table `id_companies`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_agg` to aggregate multiple rows into an array.

Compare:

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    generate_series(1, 100) AS list(id);
```

will get 100 rows,

```
SELECT
    array_agg(id)
FROM
    generate_series(1, 100) AS list(id);
```

will get 1 row with array of 100 elements.